# How to make a speedometer like chart in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I want to develop a speedtest-like application. Everything is good but I am not able to implement chart like speedometer in Angular 2/4. I am surfing too much but I am getting speedometer chart only in JavaScript. Please someone help me to do so. If some have already implemented speedometer chart in angular or tell me that how to implement JavaScript chart in angular 2/4

Comment: Have you look amcharts library ? here is demo https://www.amcharts.com/demos/angular-gauge/

Comment: yes i see that chart but it it in JavaScript not in angular.

Comment: You can easily by [this dependency](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts3-angular2) for angular2+, just make sure you add amcharts relavent scripts in index.html

Comment: Thank you  Javascript Hupp Technologies.

Comment: Get ride of this ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the angular 2 google chart
Using the Gaugh chart in angular 2 google chart you can make a speedometer like chart. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-google-chart

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [ngx-charts](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts) from swimlane. I have used it and it's very well done.

Gauge (like speedo) demo chart can be seen here:
https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/gauge

Comment: Thank you rmcsharry